# Webpack with Proxy - The development server has disconnected

Tags: reactjs, nginx, npm, webpack, docker-compose

In my React app, I'm getting the following error about a minute after connection is established:

```
The development server has disconnected.
Refresh the page if necessary.
```

If I refresh, it connects again, only to disconnect after a minute again.

Webpack was installed via `create-reac-app`.

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-alert": "^5.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.5.3",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-player": "^1.13.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "spotify-web-api-js": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.11.2"
  }
}
```

I use a `nginx` proxy reverse, with the following configuration:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass        http://client:3000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

  location /users {
    proxy_pass        http://web:5000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

If I go to `http://localhost:3000/`, I don't face the issue, so it must be related to proxy.

**Log**:

```
client_1 ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://171.13.0.12/
client_1 ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
client_1 ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/src/app/public
client_1 ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
Starting the development server...
```

---

This is my `webpack.config.js` file:

https://pastebin.com/HF78WjLL

---

EDIT: I have tried, based on the answer below, to add my network to `package.json`, like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "HOST='0.0.0.0' react-scripts start",
    ...,
  }
```

But the same error persists, just like before: it connects and quickly disconnects.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Can you share your webpack config? You need the webpack dev server to run on `0.0.0.0` for it to be reachable outside the container.

Comment: and where do i configure that? It is a very large file `webpack.config.js` in react-scripts, is that the one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `react-scripts` `3.3.0` working with proxy was the problem, indeed.

According to the recent issue: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8203,

> This is related to nginx's default [`proxy_read_timeout`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout)  **60s rule**. It seems that prior `react-scripts` versions would reload the websocket connection when it timed out after 60s.

So, adding the following lines to nginx's `dev.conf`, like so:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass        http://client:3000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    # the following two timeout rules fix CRA WDS disconnects after 60s
    proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
    proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
  }
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The webpack dev server runs on localhost by default. Localhost is only accessible from within the container. To allow it to be accessible from the host, (i.e. outside of the container), you need to make webpack serve the bundles on a publicly reachable address, `0.0.0.0`.

Add this to your config:

```js
const config = {

  ...,

  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
    host: '0.0.0.0'
  }

 ...,

}
module.exports = config
```

Comment: thank you. please refer to my edit where you can find my full config file and cross reference with your answer

Comment: simply adding your snippet at the bottom of `webpack.config.js` and building client again did not solve the problem, but I'm not sure of how to go about this 'add to your code'.

Comment: You can check the webpack docs on [devServer](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) for more information about configuring it for your project. You can also [configure](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2954#issuecomment-322233383) the host as an env for create-react-app.  Don't be afraid to roll your sleeves up and dig into your code and the documentation yourself!